# Compare two dictionary lists, based on specific key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement

I'll try to be the more concise that I can.

Two dictionary lists as follows:

```
dictlist1 = [{'name': 'john', 'age': 30}, {'name': 'jessica', 'age': 56}, {'name': 'kirk', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'mario, 'age': 25}]

dictlist2 = [{'name': 'john', 'job': 'engineer'}, {'name': 'jessica', 'job':'nurse'}, {'name': 'mario', 'job': 'electrician'}]
```

My objective is to match base on the key "name" on both dictionaries and, at the end, create a third dictionary list with the key that has no match, in this case {'name':'kirk' , 'age':20}, like this:

```
listfinal = [{'name': 'kirk', 'age': 20}]
```

I've tried successfully compare the equal keys, creating a new dictionary with keys that matches and adding "job" key to it, doing this:

```
    for dict2 in dictlist2:
        for dict1 in dictlist1:
            if dict1['name'] == dict2['name']:
                matchname1 = dict2['name']
                dictoutput = {'name': matchname1, 'age': dict1['age'], 'group': dict2['group']}
                templist.append(dictoutput)

    for dictionay in templist:
        print(dictionay)

    Output:

    {'name': 'john', 'age': '30', 'job': 'engineer'}
    {'name': 'jessica', 'age': '56', 'job': 'nurse'} 
    {'name': 'mario', 'age': '25', 'job': 'electrician'}
```

But absolutely no luck to get kirk user alone, not even using "else" in the inner if statement or creating a new if statement and using not equal (!=). I always get all the users when printing.

Any orientation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Make a list of all the names that *do* appear in both (which you have all but done); then any names *not* in that list are ones you want.

Comment: Your definitions of `dictlist1` and `dictlist2` are not valid Python.

Comment: Thanks, @ScottHunter. I'll make the proper corrections! It was used as an example, but I understand the point.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate the lists and then collect the indices of matched pairs in a list inside the loop and delete corresponding elements outside the loop.

```
matched_d1 = []
matched_d2 = []

for j2, dict2 in enumerate(dictlist2):
    for j1, dict1 in enumerate(dictlist1):
        if dict1['name'] == dict2['name']:
            matchname1 = dict2['name']
            dictoutput = {'name': matchname1, 'age': dict1['age'], 'group': dict2['group']}
            templist.append(dictoutput) 
            matched_d1.append(j1)
            matched_d2.append(j2)
            
for j in sorted(matched_d1, reverse = True):
    dictlist1.pop(j)

for j in sorted(matched_d2, reverse = True):
    dictlist2.pop(j)

ans = dictlist1 + dictlist2
```

Comment: Many thanks, @freude ! This was perfect to understand the list index where the "different" dictionary is located.

Answer (score 0):

you can use set operations to get the unique name, first make a set of the names on each one and subtract both, then use that to get the appropriate item form the list

```
>>> name1 = set(d["name"] for d in dictlist1)
>>> name2 = set(d["name"] for d in dictlist2)
>>> name1 - name2
{'kirk'}
>>> name2 - name1
set()
>>> unique = name1 - name2
>>> listfinal = [d for n in unique for d in dictlist1 if d["name"]==n]
>>> listfinal
[{'name': 'kirk', 'age': 20}]
>>>
```

Additionally, looking at @freude answers, you can make it a dictionary of name:index for each list an subtracts its keys, given that they [dict.keys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) behave set-like in order to avoid a double loop from before to get the right item from the list

```
>>> name1 = {d["name"]:i for i,d in enumerate(dictlist1)}
>>> name2 = {d["name"]:i for i,d in enumerate(dictlist2)}
>>> unique = name1.keys() - name2.keys()
>>> unique
{'kirk'}
>>> [ dictlist1[name1[n]] for n in unique]
[{'name': 'kirk', 'age': 20}]
>>>
```

Comment: This won't catch "umatched" names from `dictlist2`.

Comment: @ScottHunter just do the same for the other case, just exchange the role of dictlist1 and dictlist2

Comment: One more way to do it. Thanks @Cooperfield ! Learning fromall of you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sets` to find the names that are only in `dictlist1`, in `dictlist2` and also the common names. Then create the `listfinal` by keeping only the item with the `name` not in the common names:

```py
dictlist1 = [{"name": "john", "age": 30}, {"name": "jessica", "age": 56}, {"name":"kirk" , "age": 20}, {"name": "mario", "age": 25}]

dictlist2 = [{"name": "john", "job": "engineer"}, {"name": "jessica", "job": "nurse"}, {"name": "mario", "job": "electrician"}]

names_dictlist1 = {item["name"] for item in dictlist1}
names_dictlist2 = {item["name"] for item in dictlist2}

common_names = names_dictlist1 & names_dictlist2

listfinal = [item for item in dictlist1 + dictlist2 if item["name"] not in common_names]
```

Comment: OMG... this made the trick.! Much appreciated! I tried so many times the loop that I forgot about the real issue... I totally put aside the logic behind the last line!

Answer (score 0):

If you want one-line solution there it is

```
print([person for person in dictlist1 if person['name'] not in map(lambda x: x['name'], dictlist2)])
```

This code prints element from fist list wich "name" key doesnt occur in second list

Comment: Another perfectly line that allow this to work! This is so simple and neat. Thanks!